# Cannot read property 'errors' of undefined at Object.eval angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-material

Tengo un formulario de login que tiene autenticacion basica con spring security, y me sale un error en el `html`.
**Este es mi `html`, estoy usando `angular material`:`**

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" >

  <div formGroupName="loginGroup">

    <div class="internal-form-container">
    <div> <!--USER NUMBER-->
      <mat-form-field class="input-full-width" appearance="outline">
        <mat-label> User Number</mat-label>
        <input matInput
               placeholder="User name"
               maxlength="100"
               formControlName="userName"
               [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.userName.errors}">
        <mat-error *ngIf="f.userName.error?.required"> Must be filled</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>

    <div><!--PASSWORD-->
      <mat-form-field class="input-full-width" appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
        <input matInput
               [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'"
               placeholder="Password"
               maxlength="50"
               formControlName="password"
               [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': submitted && f.password.errors }">
        <mat-error *ngIf="loginForm.get('loginGroup.password').hasError('required')"> You must enter a password</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox"><!-- check Box-->
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"> Remember Password
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="button-container"> <!--BUTTONS-->
    <button class="btn rounded-btn button" >{{ 'Login' }}</button>
    <button class="btn rounded-btn button" routerLink="/">{{ 'Cancel' }}</button>
    <div> <!-- aqui va el error si no encuentra el usuario correcto-->
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Este es el TS:**

```
import { routerTransition } from '../../router.animations';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {AuthService} from '../../shared/guard/auth.service';
import {first} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss'],
   animations: [routerTransition()]
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
 loginForm: FormGroup;

 hide = true;

 form: any = {};
 submitted = false;
 loading = false;
 returnUrl: String;
 errorMessage = '';

constructor(
    private translate: TranslateService,
    public router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private formbuilder: FormBuilder,
    private authService: AuthService,
    ) {
        this.translate.addLangs(['en', 'fr', 'ur', 'es', 'it', 'fa', 'de', 'zh-CHS']);
        this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');
        const browserLang = this.translate.getBrowserLang();
        // this.translate.use(browserLang.match(/en|fr|ur|es|it|fa|de|zh-CHS/) ? browserLang : 'en');

        this.loginForm = this.formbuilder.group({
          loginGroup: this.formbuilder.group({
            userName: ['', Validators.required],
            password: ['', Validators.required],
          })
        });

        // reset logout status
        this.authService.logout();

        // gets return url from route parameters or default to '/'
        this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap['returnUrl'] || '/';
    }

ngOnInit() {}

onLoggedin() {
    localStorage.setItem('isLoggedin', 'true');
}

get f () { return this.loginForm.controls; }

onSubmit() {
  this.submitted = true;

  // stop here if the form is invalid
  if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
    return;
  }

  this.loading = true;
  this.authService.loginUp(this.f.userName.value, this.f.password.value)
    .pipe(first())
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
      },
      error1 => {
        this.errorMessage = error1;
        this.loading = false;
      }
    );

}
```

**y este es el error que me muestra al correr**:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si alguien conoce algun resultado le agradeceria mucho.

Comment: f.password no existe, ése es el problema

Comment: en el metodo get estoy llamando:

        get f () {return this.loginForm.controls}

Comment: Ops, es verdad... El problema es userName/userNumber

Comment: Me sigue saliendo el mismo error bro

Comment: Con el código que tienes no puedo reproducir el error, los imports no coinciden con las clases que estás usando, por ejemplo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega el safe navegation a f.username, que al parecer f.username es indefinido al comienzo de la aplicación.

```js
        <mat-error *ngIf="f.userName?.error?.required"> Must be filled</mat-error>
```

Comment: muchas gracias bro, me sirvio